# How to create JQuery Data with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i want to create a diagram with a jquery Plugin (tufteGraph).

I have to give some data information for the Plugin:

```
  jQuery('#awesome-graph').tufteBar({

            data: [[5, {label: "Bar1"}],[6,{label: "Bar2"}]]
            },
            [...]
```

How can i put data into that, i build with a JS loop?

```
var datas;
for(var i = 0; i < zi; i++)
                {
                    if (i < zi - 1)
                    {                        
                        datas+="["+timefield[i]+", {label: "+SelectObjects1[pX][i][1]+"}],";                   
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        datas+="["+timefield[i]+", {label: "+SelectObjects1[pX][i][1]+"}]]";                
                    }
                }
```

How can i use the "datas" data inside the JQuery function?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not build it as a string, but as an array directly

```
var datas = [];
for(var i = 0; i < zi; i++)
    {                      
      datas.push( [timefield[i], {label: SelectObjects1[pX][i][1]}] );      
    }
```

and use it

```
jQuery('#awesome-graph').tufteBar({
            data: datas
            },
            [...]
```